# Cannot initialize CGFloat in a Singleton class

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

When I initialized a CGFloat in a singleton class, It showed this error. Why can't I initialize a CGFloat in a singleton class ?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of the code, include the code itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearing the concept as said by [martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) sir in comment.

> Actually CGFloat is defined in CoreGraphics (and CoreGraphics is
>   included from UIKit on iOS, and from AppKit or Cocoa on OS X).

Unfortunately the solution is very simple. Singletone class does not contain UIKit headerfile bydefault. so,

It turns out that CGFloat belongs to the UIKit Framework, which is not present in a custom (Swift) class and that is where the error happened. So to fix it: just import UIKit.

```
import UIKit
```

Try this.

**Note:-** Swift Playground does not produce the error, just the Swift File.

Comment: Got it, Thanks for the reply !!

Comment: Actually CGFloat is defined in **CoreGraphics** (and CoreGraphics is included from UIKit on iOS, and from AppKit or Cocoa on OS X). Also UIKit is not a class but a framework.

Answer (score 1):

`CGFloat` is a type in `UIKit`. Try importing `UIKit` into your class

Comment: I always try to be Swift ;-)